# ElasticSearch - Index per database

Tags: oracle, elasticsearch

I'm trying to understand something and didn't find relevant answers for this.

I'm building a system that will sync some databases with ElasticSearch and I'm digging information about the structure I would need.

Some details:

- My clients use a Web ERP System, **some of them have the ERP locally, in their own server**.
- **Others use the ERP as a "PAAS"**, there are lots of JBoss'es distributed in lots of machines in the cloud. Each client have their **IP:PORT**. Each group of that ERPs points to a same **Oracle** instance, but with diferent **USERS**.
  Example: (ClientA -> Oracle1/USER_A, ClientB -> Oracle1/USER_B, ClientC -> Oracle2/USER_C).

After some researches about syncing I found three solutions:

- One big index with all documents and aliases/filter for each client.
- Index per client
- One ElasticSearch instance per client.

So, my question is, how is the best way do design my application?

**The first one** seems to be the more adopted, **BUT** my clients usually use diferent versions of the ERP (ClientA uses version 1.0 and ClientB use 1.2)
and in this case the data on their databases could be slightly different. Besides that, each client need to be able to configure what tables/fields will be synced and how (ElasticSearch Mappings), because of the unique needs of each one.
So this method seems to be impossible to use, because of that different mappings and documents, wich is impossible to achieve with one single index.

**The second one** seems to be less scalable, they said that a large amount of indices is a bad thing, **BUT** in my case, there are just a few database users, so it will not have so that much indices.
**So until now this seems to be the best aproach.**

**The third one** would be put lots of ElasticSearch'es running on different ports, one per client, and each of them would consume only his ES instance.

Thanks in advance!